# syntax error table variable

Tags: t-sql

This is the code:

```
declare @Ids table ( Id int identity(1,1));

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @Ids ON;
```

and I get:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Ids'

I cannot see what's wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) on table variables

This works

```
CREATE TABLE Ids ( Id int identity(1,1))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Ids ON
```

and this

```
CREATE TABLE #Ids ( Id int identity(1,1))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Ids ON
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks. Should have read on here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61808