# Inserting a row in identity column of table variable

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table variable:

```
declare @TestTable2 as table (A int identity)
```

I'm trying to insert some value (for instance a 1) **without altering the line of code above**.

I've been trying to do the following

```
declare @TestTable2 as table (A int identity)



SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TestTable2 ON
INSERT @TestTable2 (A)
VALUES (1)
```

But I get an error (Incorret syntax near '@TableTEST2')

How can I insert a value in the column `A`?

Comment: I used:

`declare @TestTable2 as table (A int identity)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TestTable2 ON
INSERT @TestTable2 (A)
VALUES (1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error table variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158335/syntax-error-table-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check  [MSDNlink][1] below It specifies the Restriction.

EDIT.  After it became clear that you do not want to insert a specific value (that's what `Identity_Insert` is for) all you want is to insert a new auto-generated value for columne A, then what you need to do is

```
 Insert @TestTable2 DEFAULT VALUES
```

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/757012/set-identity-insert-on-table-variables

Comment: Okey. But how can I insert a row instead?

Comment: Do you mean Insert a row with a Specific value? or just insert a new row with the next identity value?    Cause if it's the latter, you just need to use DEFAULT keyword.  `Insert @TestTable2 DEFAULT VALUES`

Comment: Link only answer huh?

Comment: The link for this answer is no longer valid. Microsoft has retired Microsoft Connect as of 1/2/2018

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible, `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is not apply on Table variables

If want use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` try to create temp table and use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` on it

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable2(A int identity)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TestTable2 ON

INSERT INTO #TestTable2 (A) VALUES (1)
```

For more info click [`HERE`](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1077.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the task by setting the statements as variables and then executing them with a concatenated statement.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- =============================================
    -- SET IDENTITY INSERT ON AND INSERT THE NEW RECORD.
    -- =============================================
    SET @STATEMENT1 = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TestTable2 + ' ON;';
    SET @STATEMENT2 = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TestTable2) + ' (A) VALUES (1);';
    SET @STATEMENT3 = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TestTable2 + ' OFF;';

    EXEC (@STATEMENT1 + @STATEMENT2 + @STATEMENT3);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```